# How to force applications on the Windows taskbar to stack?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

Some applications which I have pinned to the taskbar get split into multiple icons; ones which are pinned and those which are not.

Here is an example:

[image]

On the far left is mintty which launches mintty.exe. If I create terminal windows from that icon then they stack. If I create instances of mintty elsewhere, such as from an explorer context menu, then it stacks on a new icon.

Next is Eclipse which launches eclipse.exe. It spawns a new icon and never stacks.

Lastly is Minecraft. The first icon is the lancher which does stack. But then when the game launches it creates a new icon.

How can I get these applications to always stack without getting split into new icons?

Answer (score 0):

Choose the following option from the Taskbar settings window:

[image]

Comment: This option is already selected.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can achieve what you are asking.
The problem may be with badly-written applications and not with any of your
Windows settings.

Based on your description, you are executing one program, which then launches another.
As these are two different programs, they cannot exist as one stack.

Both programs use the same program icon, so they seem to be the same on the
taskbar, but for Windows they are not the same, so their icons are not
combined into one stack.